# How to print all lines matching the first field of last line

Tags: regex, shell, command-line, awk, sed

I've been trying to do this for the last two days. I read a lot of tutorials and I learned a lot of new things but so far I couldn't manage to achieve what I'm trying to do. Let's say this is the command line output:

```
Johnny123   US  224
Johnny123   US  145
Johnny123   US  555
Johnny123   US  344
Robert  UK  4322
Robert  UK  52
Lucas   FR  344
Lucas   FR  222
Lucas   FR  8945
```

**I want to print the lines which match 'the first field (Lucas) of last line'.**

So, I want to print out:

```
Lucas   FR  344
Lucas   FR  222
Lucas   FR  8945
```

Notes:

- What I'm trying to print have a different line count each time so I can't do something like returning the last 3 lines only.
- The first field doesn't have a specific pattern that I can use to print.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is another way using `tac` and `awk`:

```
tac file | awk 'NR==1{last=$1}$1==last' | tac
Lucas   FR  344
Lucas   FR  222
Lucas   FR  8945
```

The last `tac` is only needed if the order is important.

Comment: Awesome. It works. Can you please explain to me the part '{last=$1}$1==last'. I searched for 'NR==1' and I understand now it means one record but what about the rest of the code? I'm just trying to understand so if I encountered other issues that can been solved using awk.

Comment: @Sameh You're welcome. Sure, `last` is just a variable that we assign the value of first column when it is the first line (keeping in mind that `tac` has already reversed the file for us). `$1==last` is a test condition. If it is true, we will print the line.

Comment: Great! Thank you so much. One last thing, this code will be used in an online tool so it will run a lot. Performance-wise, which will be more efficient? Yours or Ed Morton's answer?

Comment: @Sameh You can run both commands using one of your production file with `time` command (just put `time` in front of the command shown above, `time tac file ...`)and see the performance. My guess is both should take fairly the same amount of time. `tac` might be a little quicker since it is a `C` utility meant to reverse the file but I may be biased towards my answer. `:)`.

Answer (score 3):

```
awk 'NR==FNR{key=$1;next} $1==key' file file
```

or if you prefer

```
awk '{val[$1]=val[$1] $0 RS; key=$1} END{printf "%s", val[key]}' file
```

Comment: Hi Ed. I remember your answer was the first working answer I received. Thank you so much for that. BTW, your first code doesn't print anything but the second one works fine. Also, as I asked jaypal in his answer, this code will be used in an online tool so it will run a lot. Performance-wise, which will be more efficient? Your code or jaypal's asnwer?

Comment: Did you notice that the file name is specified TWICE on the command line for the first script? wrt performance - they'll all run in about the blink of an eye for any reasonable sized file so just pick whatever one you'll be comfortable supporting, maintaining, enhancing in future.

Comment: I see. Thanks for your reply Ed. I'm not running this on a file. I'm running it on the output in the command line directly. So I think this is why it doesn't work for me right now.

Comment: Right, the first version can't be run on piped input.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -nr 'H;g;/^(\S+\s).*\n\1[^\n]*$/!{s/.*\n//;h};$p' file
```

Store lines with duplicate keys in the hold space. At change of key remove previous lines. At end-of-file print out what remains.

Comment: This also works :D. Where i can get the idea about complex sed commands(_like this_)?

Comment: @AvinashRaj hover over the `sed` tag and choose `info`

Comment: There are many links in that info page. Please recommend a one for me which describes clearly about sed loops,hold space,pattern space, labels.

Comment: @EdMorton yep, i agree with you. Please recommend awk tutorial about arrays,loops.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Just get the book "Effective Awk Programming, Third Edition" by Arnold Robbins (the provider of gawk).